# How to access each item in a list of dictionaries in c# without using foreach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a list of dictionary like this

```
public List<Dictionary<string, object>> Data { get; set; }
```

From within the a razor view, I want to loop over the list and for each item in the list I want to display it's directory content.

Here is a screenshot of my object
[image]

[image]

Here is what I have done inside my view

```
@for (int y = 0; y < Model.Data.Count; y++)
{
<tr>

    @for (int x = 0; x < Model.Data[y].Count; x++)
    {
        <td>@Model.Data[y][x].Value</td>
    }

</tr>
}
```

But this is giving me an error

> Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.this[string]'
>   has some invalid arguments

What am I doing wrong here? How can I loop through the data correctly?

Note: I don't want to use `foreach` loop here because I need to be able to know the previous row/next row and I also want to sum some records in the view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dictionary's key is `string` type, but in your code you are passing an integer value as the key (*value of variable  x*) when trying to access the value.

You may iterate through the dictionary keys and use that to get each item value.

This should do it.

```
@foreach(var  key in Model.Data[y].Keys)
{
    <td>@Model.Data[y][key].Value</td>
}
```

Or even a fullblown `foreach` solution

```
@model SomeClassWhichHasTheDataPropertyWhichIsTheDictionary
@foreach(var dict in Model.Data)
{
    <tr>
     @foreach(var key in dict.Keys)
     {
        <td>@dict[key]</td>
     }
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Data)
{
    <tr>
    foreach(var key in item.Keys)
    {
        <td>item[key]</td>
    }
    </tr>
}
```

> Why you get this error message?

The reason is that the keys of your dictionaries are strings, not integers.

```
Dictionary<string, object>
```

Comment: I don't want to use foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary's keys are strings, not integers. But if you don't want to use a `foreach` on the dictionary, you can copy the key-value pairs into a list, and walk through that in a conventional `for` loop:

```
@for (int y = 0; y < Model.Data.Count; y++)
{
<tr>
    var kvpairs = Model.Data[y].ToList();

    @for (int x = 0; x < kvpairs.Count; x++)
    {
        var o = kvpairs[x].Value;
        <td>@o</td>
    }
</tr>
}
```